# WM_APPCOMMAND to control Volume & Mute using C#

Tags: c#, system, volume, mute

I have the below code working in my C# program to control `system VOLUME _UP _DOWN _MUTE`, etc.

I do this using `WM_APPCOMMAND` messages; however, (*and this is a BIG however*) I am wondering if it ONLY works because I use a Keyboard with `HOTKEYS`, i.e.(browser, power, media player, email, etc.)  the buttons at the top of the keyboard above the Function Keys.

I would like to know if my code will work on Laptops and PCs whose keyboards are not equipped with HOTKEYS?

From researching I see that this `WM_APPCOMMAND` stuff goes all the way back to 2001 in some message threads, so I suspect it is pretty stable on XP, Vista and now Windows 7 & 8. And it does not appear to be deprecated as companies like Logitech and other keyboard/media console manufacturers still use it for new products.

I just need to if it works for keyboards without *HOTKEYS*.

Thanks!

Anthony

```
private const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 8;
private const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 9;
private const uint APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 10;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


//APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN
SendMessageW(this.Handle, WmAppcommand, this.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);

//APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP
SendMessageW(this.Handle, WmAppcommand, this.Handle, (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
```

Comment: No, it is not your keyboard that plays the song.  All that the keyboard does is generate a keystroke event when such a button is pressed.  Which gets translated to a WM_APPCOMMAND.

Comment: Thanks Hans. So you are saying that an application using WM_APPCOMMAND will work (to Mute, decrease increase Vol, etc.) even if the PC or laptop used does not have a special keyboard.  Right?

Comment: ...and I do it programmatically without needing any physical keystrokes.  For instance, my WinForm application has a button that mutes the sound.  Correct?